# How can I get HTML output from NBoilerPipe?

Tags: .net, html, mono, boilerpipe

NBoilerPipe is a Mono port of the BoilerPipe Java library. I've managed to get this working in .NET 4 without too much trouble (a few library references needed fixing/etc). However, searching through the code, I cannot find any 'hooks' for HTML output. For example, the GetText() method only has one parameter for the input, and I cannot see any additional methods. How can I get HTML output from NBoilerPipe?

Here is the sample NBoilerPipe code that is working in .NET4:

> ```
>           String url = "http:// <etc> ";
>         String page = String.Empty;
>         WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create (url);
>         HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();
>         Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream ();
>         using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader (stream, Encoding.UTF8)) {
>             page = streamReader.ReadToEnd ();
>         }           
>         String text = ArticleExtractor.INSTANCE.GetText (page);
>         Console.WriteLine ("Text: \n" + text);
> ```

Comment: Isn't the purpose of NBoilerPipe to extract the text from html? I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Boilerpipe extracts the content from the page, filtering the 'boilerplate' - things like header, footer, menus, advertising,etc. The original BoilerPipe can return the content as HTML fragments, or filtered further to give text. THe HTML fragments are useful because they include things like p tags.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I managed to solve it by using the following.

http://boilerpipe-web.appspot.com/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The above link is a free request-limited web service to the Java library. Only suitable for home experimentation imho.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, and I'm not familiar with .Net (though
it looks like Java to me), and I'm also not an expert programmer by any
means, but I think this may help others with a similar question.

The `INSTANCE` method you're using returns only text. If you
want to get HTML you need to create a `BoilerpipeExtractor` and an
`HTMLHighlighter`. Then you can use its `process` method to get what
you're looking for.

```
final BoilerpipeExtractor extractor = CommonExtractors.ARTICLE_EXTRACTOR;
final HTMLHighlighter hh = HTMLHighlighter.newExtractingInstance();
```

The `.newExtractingInstance()` is the one that gives you just the relevant
HTML. The other option is `.newHighlightingInstance()`, which highlights
the main text but keeps the whole HTML document intact.

All you need to do after that is to call the `HTMLHighlighter`'s `process`
method:

```
System.out.println(hh.process(url, extractor));
```

`process` can also be `process(TextDocument doc, InputSource is)` or
`process(TextDocument doc, String origHTML)`.

Look through the source code in the [Github repo](https://github.com/kohlschutter/boilerpipe/blob/2c78035a830282e2435c466f3f14d6d4104d0a94/boilerpipe-demo/src/main/java/com/kohlschutter/boilerpipe/demo/Oneliner.java). There are notes
on what everything does. I looked for the Javadocs, but I can't find
them anymore.

Find a demonstration of pretty much exactly this at
[HTMLHighlightDemo](https://github.com/kohlschutter/boilerpipe/blob/2c78035a830282e2435c466f3f14d6d4104d0a94/boilerpipe-demo/src/main/java/com/kohlschutter/boilerpipe/demo/HTMLHighlightDemo.java) in the same repo.